# UnicodeString::Delete Method

Tags: c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I have a Unicode string that I want to limit to 30 characters.  I populate the string from a query, so I don't know the length to begin with. I want to simply snip off all of the characters past 30. I found the [`UnicodeString::Delete()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.UnicodeString.Delete) method, but I don't know how to use it.

I tried this to no avail:

```
mystring = <code here to populate the unicode string mystring>
Delete(mystring, 30, 100);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are actually trying to call [`System::Delete()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Delete), which is not available to C++, only to Delphi.  Internally, `UnicodeString::Delete()` calls `System::Delete()` using `this` as the string to manipulate.

`UnicodeString::Delete()` is a non-static class method.  You need to call it on the string object itself, not as a separate function.  Also, `Delete()` is 1-indexed, not 0-indexed:

```
mystring.Delete(31, MaxInt);
```

If you want to use 0-indexing, use [`UnicodeString::Delete0()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.UnicodeString.Delete0) instead:

```
mystring.Delete0(30, MaxInt);
```

However, the [`UnicodeString::SetLength()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.UnicodeString.SetLength) method would be more appropriate in this situation:

```
if (mystring.Length() > 30)
    mystring.SetLength(30);
```

Alternatively, you can use [`UnicodeString::SubString()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.UnicodeString.SubString)/[`UnicodeString::SubString0()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.UnicodeString.SubString0):

```
mystring = mystring.SubString(1, 30);
```

```
mystring = mystring.SubString0(0, 30);
```