# UnicodeString Delete Method (different result between 32-bit Win and iOS/Android)

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, c++builder-tokyo

I'm building a simple FMX app in C++ Builder (Tokyo 10.2.3) that displays agenda data from an SQLite db. I've added a `TComboBox` to let the user filter what is presented. The combo box has the following items added to it at runtime (these are committee names):

```
Show PSSC
Show TD
Show RRMS
```

I'm using the combo box to add a filter to an SQL query on the database. The data set has a field `committee` and each row of data belongs to one of those 3 committees (PSSC, TD, RRMS).

Below is my code to add the filter into a query. It works fine on 32-bit Windows but not on iOS or Android. All I'm doing is trimming off the `"Show "` with the `.Delete` to the `UnicodeString mystring`.

```cpp
mystring = Form1->cmbBoxFilters->Selected->Text;
mystring = mystring.Delete(1, 5);
query->SQL->Text = "SELECT * FROM mtgs WHERE weekday = '" + myday + "' AND committee = '" + mystring + "'";
```

Here is what is happening, in 32-bit Windows `mystring` is exactly as it should be. If i select "Show PSCC" from the combobox, then `mystring` ends up "PSCC" and the query works great. But, when I run on iOS or Android `mystring` ends up "SSCC". The first letter of whatever is selected becomes an S. I can't for the life of me figure out why.

I'm posting because I'm just curious as to how this "S" is showing up in my original code on iOS or Android and not 32-bit Win.

p.s. Just using `TFDConnection`, `TFDQuery`, and `FDPhysSQLiteDriverLink` on my Firemonkey form.

Comment: Evidently on these platforms `Delete()` indexes characters from zero, so it deletes characters from second to sixth inclusive.

Comment: Thanks GSerg - you are correct and I couldn't see the forest for the trees.  I can circumvent the problem using the 0-indexing method like Remy explains here:  [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51623840/unicodestringdelete-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like a difference in the compilers, with mobile compilers (iOS/Android) indexing from 0 and desktop compilers (Windows/OSX) indexing from 1. Thanks to GSerg for pointing that out.

Here is a solution that explicitly uses 0-indexing for all platforms.  The only changes are the `0` you see added to the end of `.Delete` and also inside the parenthesis:

```
mystring = mystring.Delete0(0, 5);
```

This code works the same on Windows, iOS, and Android.  Thanks to an old post from Remy: [UnicodeString::Delete Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51623840/)

Comment: Given that both `Delete` and `Delete0` exist, `Delete` behaving like `Delete0` ought to be a bug in the library implementation.

Comment: It is not a bug, actually. Delphi-style strings really are 0-indexed on mobile platforms, and 1-indexed on desktop platforms (this is documented behavior). In Delphi, there is a way to turn that off in Pascal code (the `{$ZEROBASEDSTRINGS OFF}` directive), but there is no similar option in C++. The `UnicodeString::Delete()` method is designed to match the Delphi behavior (see the `_DELPHI_STRING_ONE_BASED` conditional), which is why the `Delete0()` and `Delete1()` (and other similar `0`/`1`) methods were introduced for people who want/need consistent indexing across multiple platforms.

Comment: Was just about to submit bug report.  Glad I saw this first.  Thanks Remy.